# ambiguity when decomposing pitch (yaxis rotation) from rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigen, rotational-matrices

I am given a 4x4 pose of a robot where the z axis is facing forward, x-axis is facing east (right) and the y axis is point downwards.

Now, to extract the heading of the robot, I used the following function

```
void inline mat2xyh(Matrix4f& pose, float &x, float &y, float &heading){
    heading = atan2(-pose(2, 0),  sqrt(pose(2, 1) * pose(2, 1) +  pose(2,2) * pose(2,2)) );
    x = pose(0, 3);
    y = pose(2, 3); 
};
```

To validate, I setup the code below. When I examined the decomposed matrix angle and the angle i used to construct the rotation matrix, they don't match!

This was when I found out that there is 2 unique solutions for pitch, or that the range for pitch is `-PI/2 < pitch < PI/2`.

**Now I have no idea the robot is facing 45 degrees or 135 degrees, is there any ways around this?**

```
    Vector4f v(0, 0, 1, 0);

    MatrixXf rotation = AngleAxisf(135 * M_PI/180., Vector3f::UnitY()).toRotationMatrix();
    float x,y,h;
    Matrix4f pose1 = Matrix4f::Identity();
    pose1.topLeftCorner<3,3>() = rotation;

    mat2xyh(pose1, x,y,h);

    cout << pose1 << endl;
    cout << rad2deg(h) << endl;
    cout << "Pose: \n" << pose1 * v << endl;

    cout << "====================" << endl;

    MatrixXf rotation2 = AngleAxisf(45 * M_PI/180., Vector3f::UnitY()).toRotationMatrix();
    Matrix4f pose2 = Matrix4f::Identity();
    pose2.topLeftCorner<3,3>() = rotation2;

    mat2xyh(pose2, x,y,h);

    cout << pose2 << endl;
    cout << rad2deg(h) << endl;
    cout << pose2 * v << endl;
```

**Results**

```
-0.707107         0  0.707107         0
        0         1         0         0
-0.707107         0 -0.707107         0
        0         0         0         1
heading: 45
Pose: 
 0.707107
        0
-0.707107
        0
====================
 0.707107         0  0.707107         0
        0         1         0         0
-0.707107         0  0.707107         0
        0         0         0         1
heading:45
Pose: 
0.707107
       0
0.707107
       0
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about your coordinate system? Specifically is it robot-body-fixed or world-fixed? You are using inconsistent terminology, so it's hard to say whether XYZ corresponds to EDN (East, Down, North) or RDF (Right, Down, Forward). The difference is important when the robot rotates.

Comment: Also rotation around the down (Y) axis is yaw, not pitch. This may be contributing to your confusion.

Comment: Hi Neil, thank you for the reply. Yes I actually meant yaw. I am not familiar with the terminologies, but let me elaborate more. The dataset I am using is from Kitti, and that the map coordinate system is defined as the first pose of the robot at time t=0. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second argument of of `atan2` is always non-negative, you will only get angles between `-pi/2` and `pi/2`. If you want angles between `-pi` and `pi`, you can calculate, e.g.,

```
heading = atan2(pose(0, 2), pose(2,2));
```

---

Btw: As @Neil said in the comments already, 'heading' is also known as 'yaw'. 'Pitch' and 'roll' are also referred to as 'attitude' and 'bank'.

Also: It is not uncommon to have the z-axis point upwards (or downwards), and the x-axis forward, especially in areas which usually only move on a surface. And in computer vision, the z-axis points forward, while the x-axis points right. I.e., **really make sure that you know what convention your data set uses!**

To learn more about Euler-Angles I recommend reading these:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Tait%E2%80%93Bryan_angles
- http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/euler/index.htm

Comment: chtz... trying to wrap my head around what you mentioned. For heading = atan2(pose(0, 2), pose(2,2));  does it work for all scenarios e.g roll, pitch and yaw are all non zeros?

Comment: It will always give you some more or less meaningful result. If your roll or pitch gets near 90° you will likely get singularities. In these cases Euler angles are a really bad representation for rotations. though. Essentially, the question you need to ask yourself, is what do you expect 'yaw' to be?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘meaningful result’? The robot is a car moving on a somewhat planar surface with occaional small pitching and rolling, so it’s unlikely it will encounter gimbal lock? Not sure what you meant by what I am expecting yaw to be. Essentially, I am given the 4x4 pose of the robot with respective to the map, so I just need extract a fairly accurate estimate of where the robot is heading. Does that give you a better idea?

Comment: I can't help you more if you don't know what yaw angle exactly you are referring too. If your pitch and roll are about 10° you may get an error of about 1.5% depending on which convention you are using, so probably you should not worry too much about it.

Comment: Thanks! But can I understand what information do you require when you said I do not know what yaw angle I am referring to. I know  that the yaw (Its a typo when I wrote pitch sorry)I need is the rotation around the y axis, and I understood if I use different conventions I might get different results)